# How to Select the values from the range

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two columns in a table.

```
Percentage, Commission
100           20
98            19.5
97.5          19
96.25         18.5
95            18
...
80            15
```

- If my percentage is 95.25 then the commission should be 18.
- If my percentage is 97.5 then the commision should be 19.

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: What is actually the rule? Select the maximum Commission value among the rows where Percentage <= @GivenPercentage? or Select the Commision from the row with the maximum Percentage where Percentage <= @GivenPercentage?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(Commission) FROM #test
WHERE Percentage <= 96.25
```

Comment: That is a better solution than mine. Wish I would have thought of that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 Commission
from theTable
where Percentage <= 96.25
order by Percentage desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of providing another option:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rank = CASE
      WHEN Percentage > @MaxPercentage THEN 0
      ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Percentage DESC)
    END
  FROM atable
)
SELECT Commission
FROM ranked
WHERE rank = 1
```

As I said in my comment to your question, it is not entirely clear which row should actually provide the right output, the one with the maximum `Percntage` or the one with the maximum `Commission`. Based on that, you may want to replace `ORDER BY Percentage DESC` with `ORDER BY Commission DESC`.